# Why is executionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds required?

Tags: cadence-workflow

When using the Java client to start a workflow in Candece "executionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds" is required on the Workflow.  If I have a workflow that can run for an indeterminate amount of time, how do I get around this restriction?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. #1 Please provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with snippets of relevant code (HTML,CSS,etc.) so we can better help you thank you. #2 Please identify a specific and unique question in your post.

Answer (score 0):

That was a mistake to require this value. The new version of the platform I'm working on ([temporal.io](https://www.temporal.io/)) defaults this value to infinity.

Comment: Do you know if in Cadence there is any way to detect these timeouts? I don't see any logs or metrics about it.

Comment: Yes, these are reported as server side metrics.

Comment: It seems like this behaves sort of like a DLQ (remove from processing without consumer notification). If a tasklisk is so backlogged that this value is hit, these jobs seem to get lost. Is there more functionality that we can leverage in these scenarios besides a vague metric? If the backlog is like this then an in-workflow timer to fail with our own logic/logging wont work because it can't be executed right? So it seems like the safe thing to do is set this to a massive value.

Comment: Yes, it is better to set it to a massive value and use metrics to find out that the system is not healthy.

Answer (score 0):

> an indeterminate amount of time
> First of all I believe indeterminate amount of time is not infinite amount of time.
> As letting a workflow execution run and grow infinitely is anti-pattern in Cadence workflow. See `Recommendation #5` in this article https://longquanzheng.github.io/cadence-lab/book/learnings/what-should-be-in-a-workflow-or-an-activity-in-cadence.html
> A good timeout value can protect your workflow grow infinitely.

Because it's not recommended to let workflow run forever, as it will cause potential performance issue in both worker and server, the original idea is to enforce client providing a timeout value. We didn't provide defaults, as it's difficult to have a reasonable default for all use cases.

A too small default values will be even worse, because no one like workflow timeouted in production unexpectedly. Even though you can use "Reset" command to reopen it.

A too big default value, like Maxim suggests, is slightly better than too small values. But I personally disagree because that induces client forget thinking about how long the workflow will run, and how long the workflow history will grow. This will also turn out to be a production issue at some points later.

The biggest issue I see is that this required option is not friendly. It should be compiling error instead of running error. I think this is probably we can improve in Cadence -- if this is a required field, make it required at coding experience. At the same time provide some hardcoded fake "infinite" value to help some edge cases may also make sense.

Back to you question, I would suggest using some fake infinite value if you think it's indeterminate. An good example here is in Cadence system workflow: https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/11547ee6db5dd306cb507b263381a6ea94c3faf1/service/worker/scanner/workflow.go#L48